# Excel cells- show displayed text instead of value in Data Validation list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I read this topic: [Excel cells - show text different to the actual value?](https://superuser.com/questions/281431/excel-cells-show-text-different-to-the-actual-value), and now I'm trying to use it as a Data Validation list in Excel.
But when I choose for the list those cells, when I choose one of them it shows me the value data and not the display text (I'm using Microsoft 2007).

Here is an example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRv0r.png]

Instead of showing "Thursday" it shows me in the cell the value of Thursday: "5"

How can I get the chosen value of the list to show the display text and not the cell value?

**EDIT:** Please take the days of week just as an easy example, the real question is how to do that when the values are some other text (Like: 1=Dog, 2=Cat".....)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel cells - show text different to the actual value?](http://superuser.com/questions/281431/excel-cells-show-text-different-to-the-actual-value)

Comment: how can it be a duplicate if I put this question as a reference to my question?

Comment: It's ok - technically speaking your question has the same solution as the original question so some people here on SU may consider it a duplicate - but that doesn't mean you shouldn't have asked your question. You had a problem and we helped you solve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I want dog;cat;mountain lion;armadillo... etc to appear when I type 1;2;3;4... etc.

We can use conditional formatting to create a rule for each possibility.

Create a new rule. Select a rule type of `Format only cells that contain`, set the value to 3 for mountain lion, then click the format button.

In the format cells box, set the custom number format to `"mountain lion"`. Make sure to enter quotes around the text you're using so Excel understands this is text and not really a number at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My real issue is how can I fix this problem when the values are some other text, the days of week is an easy example... I edit my question.

Comment: ah I see. Hang on a tick and I'll change my answer.